# Assume $\arg(z_1)-\arg(z_2)=2n\pi$. Show that this implies $|z_1+z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I am really lost here.  Can anyone please give me a hint or two?

Comment: Hint: Show that $arg(z_1)−arg(z_2)=2nπ$ implies that $z_1 = rz_2$ for some real r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z_1=R_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_2=R_2e^{i\theta_2}$ where $R_1,R_2\ge0$ and $\theta_1-\theta_2=2n\pi$

$\implies\theta_1=\theta_2+2n\pi$ and $e^{i\theta_1}=\cdots=e^{i\theta_2}$

$|z_1+z_2|=|R_1+R_2||e^{i\theta_2}|=|R_1+R_2|=R_1+R_2$ as $R_1,R_2\ge0$

Comment: How did you get from|R_1+R_2||e^{i\theta}|to |R_1+R_2|?  Also since we are using different arguments of z1 and z2 then can we just suppose that $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$=$\theta_1$-$2n\pi$?

Comment: @cambelot, Do you know Euler Identity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: Yes I do, but what part is it are you specifically referring to?  Also how would you deal with the subscripts 1 and 2 as the problem has given rather than simply assuming a $\theta$ without a subscript?

Comment: @cambelot, Edited the answer for better understanding

Comment: How did you use the exponential term to set it equal to 1?  I'm still not understanding that and yes, I know Euler's formula.  Like which part of it are you using?

Comment: @cambelot, What is $|\cos x+i\sin x|$

Comment: |$e^{ix}$| is the answer

Comment: Another hint: $|e^{ix}|$ is constant for all real $x$